# Default specificity for questions?

Tags: discussion

It seems that a lot of energy is put into commenting on questions from new users that their question is too broad, that it should specify some reference to some specific doctrine, etc.   The pattern I have seen has been 1-3 days of comments, and then the question is either revised or closed.

Wouldn't it save a lot of time and effort to simply rule that if one does not specify a specific context, then it is understood that one is asking about how one would answer in the context of his or her domination?

Comment: Then your just asking for their denomination. Still asking questions.

Answer (score 8):

First of all, we frequently do not know the OP's denomination. Second, the OP may know the teaching of his or her denomination but be curious as to what other denominations teach. Finally, the OP may be looking for an answer that covers Christianity generally, and it is these that are deemed too broad.

On the other hand, if the answerer(s) answers in the context of his or her denomination, we can not assume that is the answer(s) the OP was looking for. This would just encourage answers to questions that, because of their broad scope, ought not be answered.

Comment: And of course many questions are from non-Christians who don't know about the many denominations or that so many issues are debated within Christianity.